# mmap right after a variable address

Tags: c, memory-management, x86-64, mmap

Is there ANY way to `mmap` memory right after a string literal? I want to make a simple implemtation of `redzoning` so that my program writes a character right after the null terminator of a string literal, and then check if it was overwritten in case of buffer overflow, my approach was to `mmap` memory right above the address of the string's null terminator.

My concern is that there might be some important data after that string literal and I might overwrite it with `MAP_FIXED`, however, `MAP_FIXED` doesn't work - `invalid argument`.

```c
void *addr; /* the address of the memory after the end of buf */
char *mmap_addr; /* This is where we put the redzone characters */
struct redzone zone; /* our zone, to be modified */
char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE] = "ABCDEFGHIG";

addr = (void *)&buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE] + 1; /* exactly after NULL terminator */

mmap_addr = mmap(addr, sizeof(zone), PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED, 0, 0);
if (mmap_addr == MAP_FAILED) /* ((void *) - 1) */
    FOO("mmap: ");
    // ....
```

Without `MAP_FIXED` the offset between `buf` and `mmap_addr` is huge. If I understand correctly, `MAP_FIXED` `mmap` exactly where `addr` is without optimizations.

Comment: `(void *)&buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE] + 1` is not right after a string literal. Assuming GCC’s extension for arithmetic on `void *`, it is the second byte after the ordinary array `buf`, not after a string literal. To get the address of the byte beyond a defined string, merely use `char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE+1] = "ABCDEFGHIG";`, and then `buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE]` is the byte after the `MAX_BUF_SIZE` bytes that form the allowed buffer, which ends with the byte `buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE-1]`.

Comment: Perhaps more interestingly, to get a buffer marked so you may not write beyond its end, map two pages of memory, use `mprotect` to mark the second one inaccessible, and set a pointer to `MAX_BUF_SIZE` bytes before the start fo the second page. Then use that pointer for the buffer. Any attempt to write beyond the buffer will yield a segment fault.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for that, but after debugging `addr` seems to point to the address that is _exactly_ after the NULL terminator of `buf`. To the second comment: I will try that, thanks.

Comment: `char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE]` declares an array of `MAX_BUF_SIZE` bytes. If there is not a null terminator within the first `MAX_BUF_SIZE` bytes, it does not qualify as a string as defined for the standard C library. If you put or find a null terminator after the first `MAX_BUF_SIZE` bytes, it is outside the array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh I get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

> Is there ANY way to mmap memory right after a string literal?

### No,

... unless you coded something in assembler (at least on Linux/x86-64) to align suitably that string literal (so that its next after last byte is page aligned).

Try for example in C:

```
 const char*literal = "literal in " __FILE__;
 printf("here is '%s' at %p (line %d)\n", 
        literal, (void*)literal, __LINE__);
```

Since a string literal is likely to have a random address (subject to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)), and its end is very probably not aligned to the page (4Kbytes).

I made a tiny C program `e.c`  (containing the three lines above) compiled it as `gcc -O -g e.c -o e` then ran it twice:

```
 % ./e
 here is 'literal in e.c' at 0x55fb00466022 (line 5)
 % ./e
 here is 'literal in e.c' at 0x558237e51022 (line 5)
```

See [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

The failure reasons for `mmap` are well documented. `MAP_FIXED` requires the first `addr` argument to be *exactly* page aligned (e.g. multiple of 4Kbytes) and a valid address. See also [getpagesize(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html).

For debugging purposes only, consider adding:

```
char cmd[64];
snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "/bin/cat /proc/%d/maps", (int)getpid())
fflush(NULL);
system(cmd);
```

to understand the layout of your virtual address space.

For some intuition, run `/bin/cat /proc/self/maps` in a terminal.

Comment: Thank you sir, do you have any clue why `mmap` returns `invalid argument` when `MAP_FIXED` is set? I don't.

Comment: I actually did read, twice. and yet I couldn't understand what argument conflicts with `MAP_FIXED`. I would rather talk in here if you can.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there ANY way to mmap memory right after a string literal?

NO, there is no safe and reliable way to `mmap` a region relative to an object, whether string literal, ordinary array, or anything else.  In addition to the severe risk, noted in the question, that

- that memory may already be in use for something else (the stack, for example)

there are also the issues that

- the base address of the mapping must be suitably aligned (details are architecture dependent), and
- if the mapped region overlaps another memory mapping (not necessarily created explicitly by your code) then the overlapped part of the existing mapping will be discarded.

As far as ...

> `MAP_FIXED` doesn't work - `invalid argument`.

... the issue is likely that the specified address is not properly aligned.  Supposing that the required alignment is on a page boundary (typical), this is a very likely outcome for trying to `mmap` an arbitrarily chosen address.

According to the notes on [the Linux manual page for `mmap()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> The only safe use for `MAP_FIXED` is where the address range specified by `addr` and `length` was previously reserved using another mapping

Answer (score 0):

As Eric explained in comments, that's an array, not a string literal.  A string literal would be in the `.rodata` if it existed in your program at run-time, rather than just being used as an initializer for an array in your source cdoe.

No, you can't play virtual memory tricks at run-time on the stack space where the compiler put your local variables.  Well you can, but you'll break everything, e.g. by replacing your return address (and everything else in this page of stack memory) with a fresh page of zeros, or by unmapping it as part of `mremap(MREMAP_MAYMOVE)`.

---

But just for the sake of explaining what you saw with `mmap`:

**`mmap` requires a page-aligned address**, and you didn't round your address up to the start of the next page.  (cast to `uintptr_t` for `(addr + 4095) & -4096ULL`).  It also requires a size that's a multiple of 4k.  Otherwise it returns `-EINVAL`, as documented in the [Linux `mmap(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).  (Use `man 2 mmap` locally to see it instead of the more generic POSIX man page).

> `EINVAL` We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too large, or not aligned on a page boundary).

Of course, since that's a local var in stack memory, there will be another page of stack above it in typical cases.  (e.g. in the main thread, in a process with a non-tiny amount of env vars and/or command line args.)

The `addr` argument to `mmap` is **only a hint**.  If that page is already mapped (in this case to anonymous memory as part of the stack), it will pick a totally different address.  Except with `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` so it bails out with `EEXIST`, or `MAP_FIXED` so it maps a fresh page, replacing whatever was there before!

**Use [`mremap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) or [`mprotect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) to change things about existing pages**, if your program isn't keeping anything else in that page... which won't be the case here.  The Linux-specific `mremap` is a fun system call for *large* arrays: you can grow them without copying, at the cost of at worst some TLB invalidation.  But only do it on an array you allocated with `mmap` in the first place so you have a pointer to it as a `char*` or `int*` or whatever, not an actual C `alignas(4096) static char arr[32768]` or something.  There won't be a free page after it (unless it's the last thing in the BSS), and you can't usefully move it somewhere else with mremap(MREMAP_MAYMOVE).  All references to it would still have the original address baked in to their machine code, so they'd segfault.